# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'. android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I had to change PC to work about project and when I open project i get this error, do you know what does it mean? I shouldn't change anything in gradle files. The same project works perfectly in my other PC

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/backend/common/extensions/IrGenerationExtension
```

Comment: Did you try invalidate cache & restart

Answer (score 0):

Try removing .gradle cache and then switching JDK version to 11.

File > Project Structure > SDK Location > Gradle Settings

src: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45566

Comment: nothing changed after that